# Properties involving multiplying permutations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I'd like to know how to prove these permutation cycles identities:

$(x, y)(x, y) = id \text{, where id is the identity permutation}\\ 
(x, y)(x, z) = (x, z, y)\\
(i_1,i_2,i_3,...,i_{k-1},i_k)=(i_1,i_k)(i_1,i_{k-1})...(i_1,i_3)(i_1,i_2)\\
\alpha(i_1,i_2,...,i_k)\alpha^{-1}=(\alpha(i_1),\alpha(i_2),...,\alpha(i_k))\text{, where }\alpha\text{ is an arbitrary permutation (I think so)} 
$

I've proved the first three by multiplying the cycles (is there a better way?), but I don't know how to show the last one.

Comment: You multiply cycles for the last one as well.  Just break it up into two cases:  $\alpha^{-1}(i)$ is or is not among the $i_m$.

Comment: A permutation is a function, so you can prove two permutations are equal the same way we show two functions are equal: that they agree as to their results for every input argument.